# Hi I am having some problems with googlesearch module in python

Tags: python, search

I am trying to make it so that if the query is "what is python" the result should be something like:

> Python is a computer programming language often used to build websites and software, automate tasks, and conduct data analysis. Python is a general-purpose language, meaning it can be used to create a variety of different programs and isn't specialized for any specific problems

And for it I thought of using the `googlesearch` module but it returns a bunch of links like:

```
https://www.python.org/doc/essays/blurb/
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_(programming_language)
https://docs.python.org/3/faq/general.html
https://www.python.org/
https://www.coursera.org/articles/what-is-python-used-for-a-beginners-guide-to-using-python
https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_intro.asp
https://opensource.com/resources/python
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y8Tko2YC5hA
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-programming-language/
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_overview.htm
```

But I want text - I thought of making it so that it takes the answer of the query from specific sites, but after wandering around on google I couldn't find anything.

EDIT - PROBLEM SOLVED

Comment: Your post was really hard to understand so I edited it to clarify what you were saying and add punctuation. Anyway, I have questions; the example you showed, where is that text from? One of the links?  Are you wanting that to be generated somehow? Does that text show up in Google for you when you search for that query (it doesn't for me)?

Comment: @RandomDavis from the text do u mean the query? The query is "what is python" so to make it more clear the code is 
from googlesearch import search

query = "what is python?"

for i in search(query, tld="co.in", num=10, stop=10, pause=2):
    print(i)
so when i run it i get a bunch of links as i showed above but i want to see if  i can do that instead of the links text should show up for that i wanted to ask that is there a module from which i can get the answer from a specific website like wikepidia or something cause after searching for a time i coudnt get the answer from google